# Переадресация со страницы используя data-id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть очень специфическая ситуация, Есть некое кол-во постов(К примеру 10), также имеется две кнопки: Удаление, Просмотр. Нужно чтобы кнопка **Просмотр** переадресовала пользователя используя **data-id**, но всё бы ничего, но кнопка находится в очень плохом месте. Также ещё у каждого поста есть изображение со своим **id**, может так лучше будет переадресовать пользователя?

```js
// viewLinkID - значение атрибута data-id

$('span').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<button><a href=' + viewLinkID + '> [ View ]</button>')
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <title>Redirect by using element's Data-ID</title>
 </head>
 <body style="background: white;">
  <h2>Posts</h2>
  <div data-id="1">
  <h4>Post 1</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/1.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="2">
  <h4>Post 2</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/2.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="3">
  <h4>Post 3</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/3.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="4">
  <h4>Post 4</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/4.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="5">
  <h4>Post 5</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/5.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="6">
  <h4>Post 6</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/6.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="7">
  <h4>Post 7</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/7.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="8">
  <h4>Post 8</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/8.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="9">
  <h4>Post 9</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/9.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="10">
  <h4>Post 10</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/10.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Кстати, через что лучше получить **data-id**? Через метод **`data()`** или **`attr()`**?
Если есть какие-либо ошибки в коде прошу указать на них и поправить меня.

В конечном итоге у кнопки "Delete" должна появится кнопка "View" которая передрессирует на текущий пост(Пост под текущим ID/номером).

Задача заключается в том чтобы сначала у `<div>` получить значение атрибута `data-id⁣`, и используя это значение создать кнопку которая будет находиться рядом с кнопкой "Delete", и чтобы это было бы сделано для каждого `<div>`.

Comment: проблема то в чем? в том, что кнопка находится в плохом месте?

Comment: Нет, если бы, проблема в том что мне не хватает навыков чтобы каждая кнопка просмотра редиректила пользователя как я хочу. А я хочу чтобы каждая кнопка была по типу такой: ```<button href="posts/5"> [ View ]</button>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше через `data()`, так нагляднее

```js
$('div[data-id]').each(function() {
  let viewLinkID = $(this).data('id');
  $(this).append('<button><a href="post/'+ viewLinkID +'"> [ View ]</button>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <title>Redirect by using element's Data-ID</title>
 </head>
 <body style="background: white;">
  <h2>Posts</h2>
  <div data-id="1">
  <h4>Post 1</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/1.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="2">
  <h4>Post 2</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/2.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="3">
  <h4>Post 3</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/3.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="4">
  <h4>Post 4</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/4.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="5">
  <h4>Post 5</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/5.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="6">
  <h4>Post 6</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/6.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="7">
  <h4>Post 7</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/7.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="8">
  <h4>Post 8</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/8.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="9">
  <h4>Post 9</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/9.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="10">
  <h4>Post 10</h4>
  <img src=..posts/images/10.jpg>
  <span>Hello World</span>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="spbuttons">
      <button onclick="delete();"> [ Delete ]</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```